# Stopping a sibling from firing an event in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have an accordion targeting just the anchor element specified by the class "collapseLinks"
and I am trying to exclude a class "vanilla" with the `:not()` selector. Class "vanila" is just an anchor I would like to behave normally. Right now when you click on the "vanilla" anchor it fires the accordion too. Any help would be great!

```
$('a.collapseLinks').click(function() {
    $("div.slider > a.collapseLinks").click(function() {
        $(this).children(".slider > a.collapseLinks").toggle();
    });

    $(this).toggleClass('collapseLinksClicked');
});

// Stuff to do as soon as the DOM is ready;
$(".internal").hide();

$("input").attr("disabled", "disabled");

$(".slider:not(.vanilla)").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".internal:not(.vanilla)").slideToggle();
}).toggle(function() {
    $(this).children("span").text("-");
}, function() {
    $(this).children("span").text("+");
});
```

Comment: Could you please show your HTML structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first "click" handler is adding a new event handler, *every time* it is clicked, and these do not override previous handlers. Think carefully about what exactly you are trying to do, and clean up that method. Based on your description, here is a suggestion:

```
$('a.collapseLinks').click(function() {
    $(this).next("div.slider").toggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('collapseLinksClicked');
});
```

In every version of jQuery since 1.6, the correct way to disable input elements is:

```
$("input").prop("disabled", true);
```

And finally, your second 'click' handler is finding 'slider' elements (all of which I assume are `<div>` elements) and then trying to filter out 'vanilla' elements (which I assume to be all `<a>` elements). Also, no signature of the [`.toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) takes two functions as arguments.

```
$("div.slider").click(function() {
    $(this)
        .next("div.internal")
        .slideToggle().end()
        .toggle(function() {
            if ( $(this).is(':visible') ) {
                $(this).children("span").text("-");
            }
            else {
                $(this).children("span").text("+");
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use stopPropagation in the handler you do not want to propagate : http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

```
$("a.vanila").click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
  // do something
});
```

Cheers.

Comment: Perhaps you could actually show how this might be done using the OP's code.